# How to group, sort, count records and output results

Tags: sorting, python-2.7, group-by

I am trying to create a python script that does the following:

Table (dbf or csv-I could create either) will always have just 4 records. Column two (Let) will always be ordered a,b,c,d. Column 1 (Num) will always have numbers between 0-10 but frequency and order will vary. Output needs to be sorted and grouped by Num with the lowest number outputted first. If a number in the first column shows up once, just the corresponding Letter is outputted. If a number appears twice (i.e two rows have the same number), each corresponding letter is outputted with an "and" between them. If the number shows up more than twice, each letter is outputted with a comma between them and an "and" before the last letter. Each letter group that shows up gets its own line of output.

Basically looking to sort, group and output 1 of 4 options:

"No data"
1 letter by itself
2 letters separated by an "and"
3 letters separated by commas and an "and" before last letter.

Below are various versions of a table called soils_no.dbf and its desired outputs depending on input.

Num..........Let
0...............a
0...............b
0...............c
0...............d
print "No data"

Num..........Let
8...............a
8...............b
2...............c
8...............d
print c
print a, b, and d

Num..........Let
4...............a
1...............b
7...............c
3...............d
print b
print d
print a
print c

Num..........Let
3...............a
3...............b
10.............c
1...............d
print d
print  a and b
print c

Num..........Let
10...............a
10...............b
10...............c
10...............d
print a, b, c, and d

I know how to loop through and put the commas and "and" in, but I do not know how to group and sort.
Doing this with python 2.7.

BTW, I am trying to learn python, so please put an explanation of what the code means. The more I learn, the less I rely on the kindness of strangers.

A cagillion thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussion below.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def pretty_print_lst(lst):
    if not lst:
        return ""
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]
    elif len(lst) == 2:
        # Join together two letters using " and " as the join.
        return " and ".join(lst)
    else:
        # Use a "list slice" to join all in the list but the last item,
        # using ", " as the join, then append " and " and append the
        # last item.  Last item is indexed with -1, which always works no
        # matter how many or few items are in the list.
        return ", ".join(lst[:-1]) + " and " + lst[-1]

def print_rec(seq):
    # group according to counts
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for row in seq:
        n, letter = row  # get count and letter from the row
        d[n] += letter  # append letter to that count list

    # get a list of (key, value) pairs
    # so the list entries are: (count, list_of_letters)
    results = list(d.items())
    results.sort()
    if len(results) == 1 and results[0][0] == 0:
        # if all 4 letters have a count of 0, 
        print("No data")
    else:
        for count, lst in results:
            s = pretty_print_lst(lst)
            print(s)

lst = [ (8, 'a'), (8, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (8, 'd')]
print_rec(lst)
```

We use a dictionary to collect items with the same count.  This is a "defaultdict"; whenever we reference a key that does not exist, it is created, in this case with an empty list.  So we can just append values and it doesn't matter if the dict was empty or not.

Then we collect non-zero items and make a list, and then pretty-print the lists to match your desired format.

If you have any questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: My sample data may be a bit misleading. Zeroes can be dispersed throughout any of the above tables and its values returned like any of the other values, except when you have all 4 records as zero so I don't really want to strip out zeros, just print a separate response if all records are zero. Not sure if this changes code.  Also, does it matter if the table is dbf or csv for this code to work?

Comment: Additionally, sometimes in my attempt for brevity (who want to read a novel) I may omit important details (although they don't seem important at the time as I figure I can modify the text).  Take the fourth table down. Output will actually look more like:  "The letter d has a 1 order. The letters a and b have 3 orders each. The letter c has 10 orders."  Table 1 would output something like:  "There are no orders this week."

Comment: I have changed the code so that it handles zeroes as you request.  I have also added comments to help you figure it out.  As for the changes to the output text, you should edit the code and make the output the way you want it.  I'm sure you can figure out how to make the needed changes and I'll answer questions.

Comment: How can I revise this script if the second column (Let) contains a word or words instead of a letter? (like a is apple and b is banana, etc). @steveha

Comment: I see what your script does (which is helpful conceptually) but I do not know how to modify it for my situation. Firstly, the data is in a csv file that looks like what was described in original posting (header, 4 rows of data). It is not a list as you have in your code. Secondly, I also have some other data very similar to this but the second column contains words (1 or two words usually) This code puts a comma after each letter in the column rather than after all the information in the second column. Thank you for all your help. I really appreciated the comments explaining the code.

Comment: It will work just fine with a full word instead of just a letter.  Python doesn't really even have a "character" data type; a character is just a string that is only one character long.

Comment: The `print_rec()` function can take any sequence as an argument.  I showed calling it with a list, but you could pass in an iterator and it would work fine.  You can use the Python `csv` module to read the CSV file, maybe using code like this: `reader = csv.reader(open(file),delimiter=',')`  then just call: `print_rec(reader)`  The CSV reader is pretty simple; play around with it until you figure out how it works.  You could try `print(list(reader))` to just collect all the input and print it as a list, to see what it gives back.

Comment: I copied your code and ran it and the output looked like this:
    'c
a, b and d'  
I then change the list to equal:  lst = [ (8, 'apple'), (8, 'banana'), (2, 'cod liver oil'), (8, 'donut')] and the oupt looked like this:  
    'c, o, d,  , l, i, v, e, r,  , o, i and l  
a, p, p, l, e, b, a, n, a, n, a, d, o, n, u and t'  
I want it to look like this:  
    'cod liver oil  
apple, banana, and donut'